# C# experiencing unexpected symbol problem, need a pair of fresh eyes

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm experiencing this unexpected symbol problem at this line

```
Math.ClosestPointsOnTwoLines(
    Vector3 close1, 
    Vector3 close2, 
    Vector3 raypair[0].origin, 
    Vector3 raypair[0].direction, 
    Vector3 raypair[1].origin, 
    Vector3 raypair[1].direction
);
```

saying

> unexpected symbol `close1`

and need a pair of fresh eyes to spot where's wrong. I checked for typo, colon and brackets. Nothing seems wrong.

```
public class objectCoordinates : MonoBehaviour
{
    Camera cam;
    private Ray[] raypair;
    private int cnt = 0;
    private Vector3 close1;
    private Vector3 close2;

    void Start()
    {
        cam = GetComponent<Camera>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        raypair[cnt] = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        cnt++;

        if (cnt == 3)
            Math.ClosestPointsOnTwoLines(
                Vector3 close1, 
                Vector3 close2, 
                Vector3 raypair[0].origin, 
                Vector3 raypair[0].direction, 
                Vector3 raypair[1].origin, 
                Vector3 raypair[1].direction
            );
    }
}
```

Comment: remove all `Vector3` from that line!

Comment: You're specifying the type name in the parameter list, that's incorrect. Hence `unexpected symbol`

Answer (score 1):

When you call a method with parameters you don't pass in the type name there

see [Passing Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/passing-parameters)

simply remove all `Vector3` from that line and call the method only with the variable names:

```
Math.ClosestPointsOnTwoLines(close1, close2, raypair[0].origin, raypair[0].direction, raypair[1].origin, raypair[1].direction);
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need the type name when you pass the parameter. That is the (Vector3) which I removed.

```
Math.ClosestPointsOnTwoLines(close1, close2, raypair[0].origin, raypair[0].direction, 
raypair[1].origin, raypair[1].direction);
}
```